# Is there a way to modify a file and read from the new file, which has the new content?

Tags: java

When I delete a line from a text file, add it to a temporary text file, then replace the temporary file with the original, the scanner isn't loading the correct text. It is loading the content from the original file, not the updated file. I want it to load the updated file with the new content.

```
try
{
    File inputFile = new File("department.txt");
    File tempFile = new File("departmentTemp.txt");

    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(inputFile));
    BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(tempFile));

    String lineToRemove = departResIDField.getText();
    String currentLine;

    while((currentLine = reader.readLine()) != null) 
    {
         String trimmedLine = currentLine.trim();
         if(trimmedLine.startsWith(lineToRemove)) continue;
         writer.write(currentLine + System.getProperty("line.separator"));
    }

    writer.close(); 
    reader.close(); 
    inputFile.delete();
    tempFile.renameTo(inputFile);

    fWriter = new FileWriter(inputFile.getAbsoluteFile(), true);
    printOut = new PrintWriter(fWriter);
    writer = new BufferedWriter(fWriter);
    writer.write(departResIDField.getText() + "\t" + 
    departResNameField.getText() + "\r\n");
    writer.close();

    int result = Integer.parseInt(departResIDField.getText());
    depart.add(new Department(result, departResNameField.getText()));

    insResDepartModel.addElement(departResNameField.getText());

    depart.remove();

    //This is where I am having problem with the code
    //The scanner is scanning old data not the updated data             
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(inputFile);

    while(scan.hasNext())
    {
        depart.add(new Department(scan.nextInt(), scan.next()));
    }
    scan.close();

    for(int i = 0; i < depart.getSize(); i++)
    {
        Department d1 = depart.get(i);
        System.out.println(d1.departID + d1.departName);
    }

    menuLayout.show(cardLayout, "15");
    departResIDField.setText(null);
    departResNameField.setText(null);
    departUpdateButton.setVisible(false);
    departCancelButton.setVisible(false);
} catch (IOException f) 
    {
        f.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Output:
1   Biology
2   Chemistry
4   Statistics
5   Physics
3   Math

Expected Output:
1   Biology
2   Chemistry
4   Statistics
5   Physics
3   Calculus

Code removes "3    Math" and adds "3    Calculus

Comment: Show sample input, and expected vs actual outputs.

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the **desired behavior**, **a specific problem** or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. **Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers.** Flag.

Answer (score 0):

Of course there is a way. But I would recommend you to save with something like a `LinkedList`, on an text file if you want only save subjects, and try to read and write only one `File`. You can save complex data structures with `ObjectOutputStream` for example. `LinkedList` java utility has an instruction named `replace` to modify certain index. So if you want to modify the `File` you load the `LinkedList` saved then you modify the list and save it in the same file.

Comment: I am saving it to the a generic linked list that I created. The files seem to be correctly removing and adding the new code. However, the scanner is loading the original files data not the updated one. I edited the code to show where the problem is happening.

Comment: @MorrisZieve the updated one is "departmentTemp.txt" ¿right? However the `scanner` seems to be aiming to `inputfile` that corresponds to the `File` "department.txt".

Comment: Yes, the updated one is "departmentTemp.txt". The original gets deleted then teh updated file gets renamed tot he the original file "department.txt". Yes, I don't know how the scanner is getting the older data since it has been deleted.

Answer (score 0):

From my understanding, you want to replace the line containing "3 Math" with "3 Calculus". If that's the case you can do something like this:

```
    Path wiki_path = Paths.get("data/sample.txt");
    Charset charset = Charset.forName("UTF-8");

    FileInputStream fis = null;
    FileOutputStream fos = null;
    try {
      List<String> lines = Files.readAllLines(wiki_path, charset);
      int targetToReplaceIndex = -1;

      // You can modify this part to match your logic
      for (int i = 0; i < lines.size(); i++) {
          if (lines.get(i).startsWith("3 Math")) {
              targetToReplaceIndex = i;
              break;
          }
      }
      lines.set(targetToReplaceIndex, "3 Calculus");

      File temp = File.createTempFile("temp", ".tmp");
      temp.deleteOnExit();

      BufferedWriter out = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(temp));

      out.write(convertListToContent(lines));
      out.close();

      File orig = new File("data/sample.txt");

      fis = new FileInputStream(temp);
      fos = new FileOutputStream(orig);

      FileChannel src = fis.getChannel();
      FileChannel dest = fos.getChannel();
      dest.transferFrom(src, 0, src.size());

    } catch (IOException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        try {
            fis.close();
            fos.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

The method to convert a list of Strings into a single `String` is pretty straight forward using Java 8:

```
private static String convertListToContent(List<String> lines) {
    StringBuilder contentBuilder = new StringBuilder();

    lines.forEach(l -> contentBuilder.append(l).append("\n"));

    return contentBuilder.toString();
}
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Well the data successfully changes within in the files, but the scanner is adding the old data to the generic linked list I have created.